# Why does my puppy like to put his face in my neck when he sleeps?

Tags: dogs, behavior, sleep

I've noticed that when I'm in bed my puppy will lay in my arms or next to me; and then all of a sudden he walks up on me lays on my shoulder, and puts his face in my neck and goes to sleep. I don't know if it's his way of cuddling, if he just prefers the heat, or if it's his way of showing dominance of me to his brother.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like trying to get close and "cuddling". Also this way the puppy immediately notices when you're trying to leave. I wouldn't try to interpret too much into this.

Our dogs usually rest their head on my lap or shoulder when they want to beg for something, which might also be something here: "Hey, get up!" Just biting or pulling might not be an option out of respect. They'd just idle and wait patiently.

Finally, I don't think it's something about dominance. Puppies usually don't care and they start the whole dominance thing and trying to find their place in the pack by playing and toying around. You'll notice when it starts. It won't just happen by putting their head on you. That's far too calm to be honest. :)

Comment: I doubt it's begging because he only puts his face in my neck, and does nothing else afterwards. He's normally very obvious when he wants something. But thanks this helped a lot, I do tend to overthink and he probably is just wanting to cuddle.

Comment: @Hayhay28 Yeah, just  give it some time. Also forgot to mention, but the whole dominance thing will most likely start with some potential humping, no matter whether male or female. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've had many cats, but our latest addition is the **only** cat I've known that likes to rest his head on something (for the same reason that humans like resting their head on a pillow).

He sleeps like this almost always:

[image]

[image]

This seems a perfectly reasonable explanation for why your dog chooses to do so:

- It's comfortable
- It's warm
- It gives affection to a loved one

> I don't know if it's his way of cuddling, if he just prefers the heat, or if it's his way of showing dominance of me to his brother.

It's not impossible that it's related to his brother. In such a case, it's not really a matter of dominance over the brother, but rather *claiming you for himself*.

The same cat I mentioned before, also has a habit of claiming the spot closest to me. If another cat makes a move towards me, or he sees me petting them, he habitually moves in and (non-violently) drives them out.

I think this behavior ties into why he likes to cuddle me so much. Both can be explained by the cat/puppy having a very strong bond with its owner, and emotionally **needing** that bond. At least for my case, it's clear that the cat needs a lot of physical affection, and defaults to me over my girlfriend when possible.